# Facebook access token for userless polling app

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I want to write an app that tracks and displays events on specific facebook pages in a special way. The point is that the application will run on displays within environments such as clubs to draw (physical) visitors to the facebook presentation of the club. The normal facebook layout is unsuited for this kind of presentation.

Now I'm troubled by the facebook login api. It seems that only a browser can log in, with a user manually driving the flow.

I need some form of non-interactive login - there won't be any user on the machine the app is running on.

There is the app access token, but for some reason that one is *write-only*.

I don't want to post any content, my app is read-only.

As far as I'm aware, there are applications such as Spotify, that can interact with facebook without presenting users with browser-driven facebook logins all the time.

So am I overlooking something?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand what you meant completely. Probably you are looking for [Realtime Update API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)

Comment: @AnveshSaxena I'm skeptical - the example result (on the page you linked) doesn't contain any content. It just shows *what* has changed, not *how*. I still would have to query the data normally after being informed of a change and that requires those damn tokens.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena I just figured that it even says so explicitly in the paragraph directly below the example result.

Comment: I guess you want list of the events on the Facebook page.Maybe you could access the public events querying at end-point `/<page-id>/events`. Though this will provide only present or future event as there is bug in the platform due to which past events aren't retrieved.